# c++ opencv redis3m - How to store mat object to redis server and revert it back to mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, redis

Working around the clock trying to store the opencv mat object to redis server using redis3m and getting back the data from the same. Below is the code:

//Converting mat image object to byte and storing it in redis server

```
 Mat image;
   int size = (int)image.total() * image.channels();
    byte * bytes = new byte[size];
    memcpy(bytes, image.data, size*sizeof(byte));

    connection::ptr_t conn = connection::create();
    conn->run(command("SET")<<"name"<<bytes);
```

// Getting the mat data from redis server:

```
connection::ptr_t conn = connection::create();
reply r = conn->run(command("GET") << "name");

vector<char> vectordata(r.str().begin(), r.str().end());
Mat data_mat(vectordata,true);
Mat image(cv::imdecode(data_mat,1));
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html. Save as xml/yaml and upload to server.

Comment: if you got imdecode() on the receiving side, you need imencode() on the sender

Comment: Can u help me in encoding by using my code.